# ThicknessAnimation InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code inside a window method (AddServer is a user control)

```
addServer = new AddServer();
addServer.Height = 300;
addServer.Width = 570;

this.RegisterName("addServerPanel", addServer);
Main.Children.Add(addServer);

// 252, 248, 26, 0
addServer.Margin = new Thickness(252, 550, 26, 0);


ThicknessAnimation thicknessAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation();
thicknessAnimation.From = new Thickness(252, 550, 26, 0);
thicknessAnimation.To = new Thickness(252, 248, 26, 0);
thicknessAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

Storyboard.SetTargetName(thicknessAnimation, "addServerPanel");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(thicknessAnimation, new PropertyPath(MarginProperty));

Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(thicknessAnimation);

storyboard.Begin();
```

And I get an InvalidOperationException when the storyboard starts to begin. It is saying that he can't resolve the name `addServerPanel` so I think the window has not registered the name of the usercontrol. How could I fix this?

Comment: Did you try to [set target](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard.settarget) to `addServer` directly instead of using target name?

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Add this as an answer and I will aprove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using target name you can use [`SetTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard.settarget) method to set it directly to `addServer` object

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(thicknessAnimation, addServer);
```